# Using variables in DevOps YAML Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to add some conditional logic to my Azure DevOps pipeline to perform actions based on if there are pending changes in the Git repository. I've created a PowerShell script to check for changes and set a variable, which is working:

```
$gitStatus = (git status --porcelain) | Out-String

if ($gitStatus) {
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=changes;]true"
    Write-Host "##[debug]Changes found"
} else {
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=changes;]false"
    Write-Host "##[debug]No changes found"
}
```

I can then output the resulting value of "changes" in my pipeline as follows:

```
- script: echo Output - $(changes)
```

This returns "**Output - true**" as expected
If I then add the following to my YAML...

```
- ${{ if eq(variables.changes, true) }}:
  - script: echo Changes = True
- ${{ else }}:
  - script: echo Changes = False
```

I always receive "**Changes = False**"

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: i dont think this can work at all. this construction is compile time, whereas your variable is runtime

Comment: That’s unfortunate. Would there be an alternative way to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: perhaps if you use templates and parameters or different jobs and conditions, I'm not sure, i always confuse which variables\operators are runtime vs compile time

Comment: but what problem are you actually solving?

Comment: I'm using templates already as part of the wider pipeline so will look at using condition tags to branch instead of the above approach.

The problem I'm trying to solve is a little convoluted but essentially I'm connecting to Dynamics 365 CE and trying to identify if the contents of a solution has changed since the previous run (by examining the contents of the exported solution file and comparing to what is already in Git).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to input from [4c74356b41](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6067741/4c74356b41) I've come up with the following solution:

```
- script: echo Changes = True
  condition: eq(variables.changes, true)
- script: echo Changes = False
  condition: ne(variables.changes, true)
```

The final pipeline will call templates with the required actions to be performed based on the result of the check, but the above works well enough to prove the concept.